# Spacing when removing 2nd cog (12t) from Shimano 10 speed cassette

Tags: cassette

I'm converting a 10 speed Shimano 105, 11-25 cassette from
11-12-13-14-15-17-19-21-23-25 to
11-13-15-16-17-18-19-21-23-25.
This gives me kind of a "corn cob" in the middle, with bailouts on either end. I like the result very much. It shifts just fine on all the cogs, *except* ...
The chain/derailleur are not meshing properly with the 11t cog, which makes me think the spacing isn't quite right, although it looks right to my eye. And it's pretty difficult to get a good measurement with a micrometer because of the difference in height of the cogs.
Any suggestions on what might be happening and how to fix it? I could take the 11t and 13t from a 11-32 or 11-34 cassette (i.e. 11-13-15-17-...), but that's a pretty expensive solution.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing this in person. If the issue can be captured on camera, can you include a photo? Otherwise, does "not meshing properly" mean poor shifting from 11 to 13, or something else? I would generally expect poor shifting from 11 to 13 because the ramp in the 13t cog is designed to pair with the 12t cog's ramp, not with the 11t cog.

Comment: Hmmm, it is a good point. The derailleur does look somewhat misaligned (too far outboard). I will fix that adjustment, and report back. Not sure how it would have happened; perhaps I forgot a hub-side spacer.

Comment: OK ... I looked at this carefully, and I can see that when the chain is on the (smallest) 11t cog, it is rubbing against the (next) 13t cog. The chain gets sucked down a little on the front of the cassette as the cassette turns, then it clunks when it releases. I have found a source for an actual 2nd position 13t and 1st position 11t. I will update this in a few days after I have the new parts installed.

Comment: BTW, regarding shifting performance in general, I am finding the shifting across the out-of-place 16t and 18t cogs to be just fine. Any improvement provided by Shimano's carefully designed tooth profiles and alignment would not be enough for me to care. Perhaps this would be more of an issue with > 1t difference between adjacent cogs?

Comment: If you're still updating this, can you clarify if this only happens in the small chainring? If it does, then one easy not-quite-answer is that you shouldn't be using small-small anyway. In big-small, the angle the chain takes should be less steep, so it might not hit the 13t cog. I still can't quite think of why it would hit the 13t, since Shimano does have some 10s cassettes with an 11-13 sequence. It's possible the spacing isn't quite right, but the 11t cog has its own spacer, and the 13t cog is designed to mate with a cog with integrated spacer.

Comment: @WeiwenNg - The problem is not specific to the chainring, or small-small (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate the input from @WeiwenNg!
I have been able to solve this problem as mentioned in my second comment above (Nov 19 at xx:01).
What I did at first -- considering only the problematic smallest two cogs -- was to remove the 12t from the original 11-12-13 trio. The 13t appeared to have the correct indented ring to mate with the 11t. However, the spacing between the 11t and 13t was too small, and caused the chain to catch when on the 11t.
What I did to fix the problem was to obtain a 1st position 11t and a *2nd* position 13t. I used these two to replace the original 11t and 13t. (I was able to buy these individually on eBay.) Before I even installed the new cogs, I could see that they stacked higher. The spacing is now correct, and the shifting and power transfer work great.
Lesson: The smallest two cogs work as a pair. (Or at least, you need a 2nd cog that is intended to be used in the 2nd position.)